# Html email unwanted gap in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have a recurrent issue with Outlook email rendering, gaps appear in the email
It looks like lines between the table and the color of the background doesn't apply

Here is an example :
[email screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkquK.png)

I know this is an issue that is common but I couldn't find a solution with the search bar

Here is some code :

```
<table class="responsive-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" width="650" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" >
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="picto-Certifie-BIO.png" alt="Certifie BIO" width="100" height="100" /></a>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="15">&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td align="center" >
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="picto-Anti-gaspi.png" alt="Anti gaspi" width="100" height="100" /></a>
                </td>   
                <td style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="15">&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td align="center" >
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="picto-Clean-et-naturel.png" alt="Clean et naturel" width="100" height="100" /></a>
                </td>
                <td style="background-color: #ffffff;" width="15">&nbsp;
                </td>
                <td align="center" >
                    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="Picto-Fait-en-France.png" alt="Fait en France" width="100" height="100" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Thank you for your help,
Hind

Comment: Are you using a `<table>`? Please show some code

Comment: Hello yes I did, I uploaded the question

Comment: Try adding `style="border-collapse: collapse;"` to your `<table>` tag

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing here what I found out it case someone needs it:
The issue was with the tables height, so I had to find ways to reduce the height of the tables surrounding the ones with the gaps.

Here is a link that helped me (in French)
https://www.badsender.com/2019/05/28/bug-daffichage-sur-outlook-2016/